# Using Watcher API on Elastic Cloud Setup

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently got myself an elasticsearch service cloud account on https://www.elastic.co/cloud.

Currently, I try to add watchers to my setup via an automated API call.

but struggling around finding the correct API endpoint to fetch and put watchers.

I tried the following (as this is the endpoint stated in the elastic docs):

```
GET ....eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243/_xpack/watcher/watch/<watch_id>
```

which returns with a 404.

After some googling I was at least able to fetch a manual created watchers with:

```
GET ....eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243/api/watcher/watch/myTestWatchers
```

with an auth and an kbn-version header.

Unfortunately, issueing a PUT to this endpoint results in a 500 StatusCode.

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong and/or point me to the correct endpoints?
(a small working example would be really appreciated as well)

Answer (score 0):

During troubleshooting it occurred that it was indeed the correct endpoint.

The payload was somehow off and the validation for some reasons failed, resulting in a HTTP 500.